# Как можно сокращать все числа в диапазон от 1 до 4?

Tags: javascript, математика

Каким образом можно сокращать все числа например:**(1220043, 12, 34325)** в диапазон чисел **от 1 до 4**. И через циклы делил на **2**, и через `Math.sqrt()` и `Math.cbrt()` и через цикл прогнал, но не шарю как правильно это сделать?

```
for (i = 999; i > 0; i--) {
   square = Math.abs(x / 2);
   console.log(square);
   if (square <= 4) {return square;}
}
```

Comment: А что такое сокращать ? Остаток от деления на 4 +1 приведет любое число к диапазону 1-4, например ...

Comment: @Mike остаток от деление числа допустим 12313423 был в диапазоне 
от 0 до 4

Comment: Ну остаток от деления на 5, если верить тому, что обычно проходят в начальной школе, как раз лежит в диапазоне 0-4. P.S. остаток от деления - оператор `%` в JS

Comment: Чем ваш остаток отличается от результата функций `a % b`? Остаток деления на 5  будет `f(x) = (x % 5);`

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC

Comment: @Mike Я еще неправильно вопрос сформулировал, то есть есть числа разные и при деление на какое-то число получал остаток от деления в диапазоне от 1до 4. То есть эти числа могут быть 1.2, 3.4343, как реализовать это с помощью js

Comment: ну вы решите для начала, что с дробной частью делать, скажем должно ли число 1 и 1.0000000000001 давать разные результаты операции. Согласно тому что решите приведите число к целому и получайте остаток

Comment: @Mike спасибо, за помощь. От твоего "толчка в спину" нарыл алгоритм Евклида и все получилось :)

Comment: Хм. А НОД то тут каким боком

Comment: @Mike скажем долгая история :) (в.к. условия поменялись)

Answer (score 3):

Если я вас правильно понял, то все решает в один цикл

```
for (i = 999; i > 0; i--) {
   console.log(i % 5);
}
```

Ответом всегда будет число в диапазоне от 0 до 4